# xrandr as root cannot find displays

Tags: root, xrandr

I have the following rule call my script when I dock or un-dock my ThinkPad:

```
# /lib/udev/rules.d/81-thinkpad-dock.rules
KERNEL=="dock.0", ATTR{docked}=="0", RUN+="/usr/bin/think-dock-hook off"
KERNEL=="dock.0", ATTR{docked}=="1", RUN+="/usr/bin/think-dock-hook on"
```

That is the script that will be called:

```
# /usr/bin/think-dock-hook
# Find the user who is currently logged in on the primary screen.
user="$(who -u | grep -F '(:0)' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')"
su -c "bash -x /usr/bin/think-dock $setto" "$user" >> /root/think-dock.log 2>&1 &
```

And the script that is then called does something with `xrandr`.

The thing is that I can run `think-dock on` as my user (`mu`) and it works. I can `sudo -i` and run `think-dock-hook on` and it works too. But when I let `udev` run it, it just get the following error from `xrandr`:

```
# output of bash -x think-dock on
+ xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto
Can't open display
```

Now if I call `xrandr` from my `sudo -i` shell, I get:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Can't open display :0
```

However, if I do `su -c xrandr mu` from my `sudo -i` shell, I get the expected output.

So I do not really understand, the script called from `udev` fails.

Comment: `grep -F '(:0)'` should be `grep -F '(:0.0)'`; also try sticking a `DISPLAY=:0.0` in front of `/usr/bin/think-dock`

Comment: That `DISPLAY` seems good. My `who` displays `(:0)` although. So I do not think that grep would be better that way.

Comment: Okay, with the `DISPLAY` in front of `bash`, it seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: Great! My `who` had `0.0`, but anyway. Since it worked, I'll add the `DISPLAY` part as an answer; please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- *xrandr* needs to know which display you're talking about, typically via the `DISPLAY` environment variable
- `root` (which *udev* runs as) has no default `DISPLAY` set; even if he/she did, `su -c` does not preserve the environment by default
- So pass it along explicitly to bash, and that should solve your problem, e.g.:

  ```
  su -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 bash -x /usr/bin/think-dock $setto" "$user"
  ```